# Заполнить сеттеры в списке из другого списка с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Есть модель

```
@Data
public class Employee {
   private String empNo;
   private String empName;
}
```

Есть список известных значений для того, чтобы засетить их в список сотрудников

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee();
Employee employee2 = new Employee();
Employee employee3 = new Employee();
Employee employee4 = new Employee();    
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4");
```

Как используя Stream API установить для сотрудника 1 имя 1, для сотрудника 2 имя 2 итд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    User user1 = new User();
    User user2 = new User();
    User user3 = new User();
    User user4 = new User();
    List<User> users = Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3, user4);
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4");
    IntStream.range(0, users.size())
            .forEach(i -> users.get(i).setName(names.get(i)));
```

Comment: Стримы не должны работать с состоянием. Как минимум этот код менее эффективен, чем обычный цикл, как максимум является источником непредсказуемых и трудноотлаживаемых ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Streams;

List<Employee> users = Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3, user4);
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4");

Streams.zip(users.stream(),
            names.stream(),
            (user, name) -> user.setEmpName(name));
```

Comment: это офигенно!!1

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
List<Employee> employees = names.stream()
                                .map(name -> {
                                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                                    employee.setEmpName(name);
                                    return employee;
                                })
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

но естественнее будет, если определить в `Employee` конструктор принимающий одно значение

```
@Data
class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

List<Employee> employees = names.stream()
                                .map(Employee::new)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```